# Summing the same cell from multiple cells

Tags: excel

I would like to implement a formula that obtains the same value from multiple tabs

Is there any way to obtain the value from the same cell from multiple tabs? I have a spreadsheet that is separated by days of the week. Saturday-Friday. From each sheet I would like the exact same cell, for instance F232. I would like F232 from Saturday, F232 from Sunday, all throughout the week.

I wrote  the long formula. It works just fine, but is there any cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sheets are in order you can use this formula:

`=SUM(Saturday:Friday!F232)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft calls it a [3-D Reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx).